# dynamic select statement where the parameter count determines the or condition

Tags: sql, vb.net, dynamic-programming

I have a listbox with multiselect that provides multiple values.I need a select statement from the below

```
select Amount from tblEmployeeTransactions _
  where PayrollCode_Code = '" & code & "' "
```

my listboxdata is obtained as below

```
For Each drv As CListItem In lstnoncash.SelectedItems
            code =drv.ItemData
        Next
```

my desired query should be

```
select sum(Amount) from tblEmployeeTransactions _
  where PayrollCode_Code = '1' or PayrollCode_Code ='2' or PayrollCode_Code ='3'"
```

If it has 3 rows of data

Comment: You want to expand the list to an `in` statement.

Comment: A side note: Look into paramaterized queries. It's very bad practice to use concatenated string values, such as `'" & code & "'`, in your SQL statements. This can lead to SQL injection and loss of data. A simple Google search will give you a lot of information on both.

Comment: @MurDeR thats not my problem the values are coming from a listbox sourcing from my db so injections aren't the issue here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff what do u mean?sorry not getting how your addressing my problem?

Comment: as in expand list how?your answer was too brief?i dont know where am expanding the list

Comment: You want to generate the code `PayrollCode_Code in (1, 2, 3)` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this :

```
Dim a As String() = {"1", "2", "3"}
Dim query = "select sum(Amount) from tblEmployeeTransactions " _
            & "where PayrollCode_Code IN "

'here inStatement will contain : ('1', '2', '3')'
Dim inStatement = "('" & String.Join("', '", a) & "')"

Console.WriteLine(query & inStatement)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is you `PayrollCode_Code` numeric? if yes then you don't need to add single quotation for that. And I prefer to use `IN` statement instead of multiple `OR` operator.

```
Dim sCode As String
For Each drv As CListItem In lstnoncash.SelectedItems
    sCode &= drv.ItemData & ","
Next

IF sCode.Length > 0 THEN
    sCode = sCode.Substring(0,sCode.Length-1);

    Dim _SQL  As String = "Select SUM(Amount) FROM tblEmployeeTransactions " & 
      "WHERE PayrollCode_Code IN (" & sCode & ")"


    ''Execute ur _SQL
END IF
```